# How does the cpu decide which data it puts in what memory (ram, cache, registers)?

Tags: memory, cpu, cpu-architecture

When the cpu is executing a program, does it move all data through the memory pipeline? Then any piece of data would be moved from ram->cache->registers so all data that's executed goes in the cpu registers at some point. Or does it somehow select the code it puts in those faster memory types, or can you as a programmer select specific code you want to keep in, for example, the cache for optimization?

Comment: It depends on the CPU you're using, the programming language and many other factors.  Please could you provide a specific example, as well as more information about the processor language and compiler?

Comment: @MikeofSST I don't have a specific example, I'm taking an OS class and these are questions that popped into my head. I didn't really think about different implementations of this, I was looking for a more general answer if one exists or an example.

Comment: If we assume that the target processor has multiple registers, a data cache and a Memory Management Unit, as you would find on most CPUs that would be suitable for hosting a reasonably large Operating System, such as Linux or one of the Windows variants, then a good optimising compiler and the relevant OS API libraries will handle it all for you.  If you get 'under the hood' a bit by using assembly or another low-level language then you can explicitly affect the data storage locations, cache, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to this question is an entire course in itself!  A very brief summary of what (usually) happens is that:

1. You, the programmer, specify what goes in RAM.  Well, the compiler does it on your behalf, but you're in control of this by how you declare your variables.
2. Whenever your code accesses a variable the CPU's MMU will check if the value is in the cache and if it is not, then it will fetch the 'line' that contains the variable from RAM into the cache.  Some CPU instruction sets may allow you to prevent it from doing so (causing a stall) for specific low-frequecy operations, but it requires very low-level code to do so.  When you update a value, the MMU will perform a 'cache flush' operation, committing the cached memory to RAM.  Again, you can affect how and when this happens by low-level code.  It will also depend on the MMU configuration such as whether the cache is write-through, etc.
3. If you are going to do any kind of operation on the value that will require it being used by an ALU (arithmetic Logic Unit) or similar, then it will be loaded into an appropriate register from the cache.  Which register will depend on the instruction the compiler generated.

Some CPUs support Dynamic Memory Access (DMA), which provides a shortcut for operations that do not really require the CPU to be involved.  These include memory-to-memory copies and the transfer of data between memory and memory-mapped peripheral control blocks (such as UARTs and other I/O blocks).  These will cause data to be moved, read or written in RAM without actually affecting the CPU core at all.

At a higher level, some operating systems that support multiple processes will save the RAM allocated to the current process to the hard disk when the process is swapped out, and load it back in again from the disk when the process runs again.  (This is why you may find 'Page Files' on your C: drive and the options to limit their size.)  This allows all of the running processes to utilise most of the available RAM, even though they can't actually share it all simultaneously.  Paging is yet another subject worthy of a course on its own.  (Thanks to [Leeor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2016408/leeor) for mentioning this.)

Comment: 1. You specify what gets used, but the OS may decide to swap it out to disk, so you don't entirely control that. 2. Caching is usually done in line granularity, not a full page (with a few exceptions). 3. There's also the notion of scratchpads - a cache-like storage that is near and with low latency, but fully controlled by the code.

Comment: @Leeor Good points.  1) The original question didn't mention swap files or process memory mangement, so I didn't think about that aspect, although I probably should have, considering the O/P's context.  2) Yes, you are correct.  My own experience has been skewed by the evils of cache misses during ISRs in kernel mode that cause full cache flushes - bleugh!  3) I've not come across scratchpads in the architecture of the (few) processors I've worked on.  Please feel free to add a new answer, or edit mine and mark it as a community wiki answer.

Comment: Well, as you said, the question is too broad, so i'll settle with these minor correction. That's actually a good answer, +1 :)